# Sync events in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, events, fabricjs, socket.io

What I would like to do is to sync canvases between two clients with as less calls as possible. One of the best way I found would be to use Fabric Observables.

I really thought that doing (as an example) the following would work.

```
CanvasIO.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

CanvasManager.canvas.on('object:added', function(data) {
    CanvasIO.socket.emit("object:added", data);
});

CanvasIO.socket.on('object:added', function(data) {
    CanvasManager.canvas.trigger('object:added', data);
});
```

But, `trigger(event, data)` only fires the event and does not create the object.
What would be the best workaround regarding this issue? I cannot seem to find the proper methods to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not that easy. You'll need to parse the event data on your own. I mean pick target, select data you need and than send it via socket.
Secondly you have to remember that sending the object via socket requires using either .json or .send method (2nd one accepts only String).

On recive build "new Object" based on downloaded params, like this:

```
var obj = new Object(_downloadedData);
canvas.add(obj);
```

ofcourse I simplified it. 
To make it fully working you need to detect every change in canvas(move, add, index change, grouping etc.) Strip the picked events from trash data and push to socket only useful params.
(eg. you dont need to send whole object or path vector when you make a selection or simple vertical drag...).

Trust me, if you still are willing to make this collaborative canvas, than lot of work is to be done.